# Convert row_number over partition to C# linq subquery

Tags: sql

I have this SQL query below that I need to convert to linq. Im not sure how to do it especially the subquery that uses row_number

```
SELECT
                MyTablePartitioned.CounselId,
                MyTablePartitioned.EmployeeGUID,
                MyTablePartitioned.CounselDate
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                        (
                            PARTITION BY
                                EmployeeGUID
                            ORDER BY
                                CounselDate,
                                CounselId
                        ) AS RowPartition,
                        Counsel.CounselId,
                        Counsel.EmployeeGUID,
                        Counsel.CounselDate
                    FROM
                        Counsel
                    WHERE
                        Counsel.CounselDate > DATEADD(DAY, -181, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND
                        Counsel.CategoryId = (SELECT Id FROM CounselCategory WHERE CounselCategory.Description = 'Attendance')
                ) AS CounselPartitioned
            WHERE
                MyTablePartitioned.RowPartition = 1
```

Comment: Why not just keep the SQL query?`

Comment: Look at [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions).html)